# Modulus usage when dealing with odd numbers

Tags: c#, modulus, dynamic-columns

I have a list of roughly 50~60 items that I want to be able to divide into multiple columns dynamically. I'm using a nested for loop and the lists divide properly when there are an **even** number of items. However, when there are an **odd** number of items the remainder (modulus) items get left out. I've been playing around with it for a while and have not struck gold yet. I'm hoping someone smarter than me can & will assist.

Thanks.

```
    for (int fillRow = 0; fillRow < numOfCols; fillRow++)
    {
            for (int fillCell = 0; fillCell < (siteTitles.Count / numOfCols); fillCell++)
            {
                linkAddress = new HyperLink();
                linkAddress.Text = tempSites[fillCell].ToString();
                linkAddress.NavigateUrl = tempUrls[fillCell].ToString();

                mainTbl.Rows[fillCell].Cells[fillRow].Controls.Add(linkAddress);
            }

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, the problem is here:

```
fillCell < (siteTitles.Count / numOfCols)
```

That division will round down, so for example if there are 13 titles and `numOfCols` is 5, it will give 2 - which means that items 10-12 won't be used.

I suggest that actually you loop over all the *items* instead, and work out the row and column for each item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < siteTitles.Count; i++)
{
    int row = i / numOfCols;
    int col = i % numOfCols;
    // Fill in things using row, col and i
}
```

(It's not exactly clear what you're doing as you're using `siteTitles` in the loop condition and `tempSites` in the loop body, and you're not using `fillRow` when extracting the data... basically I think you've still got some bugs...)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was able to merge this with the code above, and now I can control the number of columns and items per column dynamically. =)